# How to avoid showing a Dock icon while my Electron app is launching on macOS?

Tags: electron

When creating a [`new BrowserWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window), you can set `skipTaskbar: true` to prevent it appearing in the Windows taskbar. But this doesn't work for the Dock on macOS.

For macOS we have `app.dock.hide()`, but it's not quite the same: it only hides the icon *after* your Electron app is launched. Even if you call `app.dock.hide()` as the very first thing in your main process, the Dock icon briefly appears and then disappears, which is something I want to avoid. (I want my app to only ever appear in the menu bar, similar to apps like Dropbox.)

After some more digging, I found [this issue comment](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1456#issuecomment-293518692) on the electron-builder project, which suggests the problem can be solved by setting `"LSUIElement": 1` in an `Info.plist` file included in your bundled app distribution. Apple's [docs for `LSUIElement`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-108256-TPXREF136) say this setting will indeed make the app run as an "agent app", which seems to be what I want.

Is there any way to provide this `Info.plist` setting in development, e.g. as a launch parameter for the `electron` CLI when running my app from source? Or is it really only possible to do it by bundling a full release and adding an `Info.plist` file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the property `build.mac.extendInfo` in `package.json` for additional settings to be added to `Info.plist`. https://www.electron.build/configuration/mac

Below is a sample of adding `LSUIElement` to the Mac's build settings in `package.json`.

```
"build": {
    "mac": {
        // ... other settings
        "extendInfo": {
            "LSUIElement": true
        }
    }
    // ... other settings
}
```

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question of whether its possible to do in development. Using the above electron-builder config means you need to bundle the whole release; something OP is aware of. @callum have you found a solution?